# Button in the middle of navigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to create acustom navigation bar.

I know that we can use UIButton in the middle instead of title in the navigation bar, but can we make something that look like this picture?

As you see we have three different buttons in the middle of this navigation bar. Can you share your idea with me how we can implement such a thing in iPhone?

Comment: Do you absolutely need a UINavigationBar? It's probably a lot easier to archive with a UIToolbar placed at the top

Comment: Good to know, you are welcome to share some code also as an answer, I'll check all answers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you are using a Navigation Controller you can set your navigationBar's titleView property to a UIView container that holds the three buttons in the middle (and the two sets of three dots). The code would look like something like this:

```
    UIView *buttonContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
    buttonContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIButton *button0 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button0 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
    [button0 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button0.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button0 addTarget:self action:@selector(button0Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button0 setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
    [buttonContainer addSubview:button0];

    //add your spacer images and button1 and button2...

    self.navigationItem.titleView = buttonContainer;
```

Or you could do this all in IB of course.

Answer (score 4):

Try this if your are using a UINavigationController

1. change the background image of your navigation bar with `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImageForBarMetrics:]`
2. set your left and right buttons with `[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:]` and `[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:]`. You will probably have to use UIBarButtonItem's with a UIButton as a custom view here to get rid of the border.
3. set the three buttons in the middle like this

(you probably have to change the dimensions)

```
UIView *buttonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 40)];
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button1.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button1.png"];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);

UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button2.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button2.png"];
button2.frame = CGRectMake(70, 0, 40, 40);

UIButton *button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button3.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button3.png"];
button3.frame = CGRectMake(140, 0, 40, 40);

[buttonView addSubview:button1];
[buttonView addSubview:button2];
[buttonView addSubview:button3];

self.navigationItem.titleView = buttonView;
```

Comment: +1 for your help. The way that you set `imageview.image` did not work for me but this one worked : `[button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button0.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: Oh yeah that's correct, sorry about that