# How do I get two buttons in the center of a navigation bar ios

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

[image]

I would like to implement the following image in Swift for my navigation bar.  I have tried the following code, however, it just stack the buttons on top of each other

```
let fromButton:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,80,44))
let toButton:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(80,0,80,44))

fromButtonView.bounds = fromButton.frame
fromButton.addSubview(fromButtonView)

toButtonView.bounds = toButton.frame
toButton.addSubview(toButtonView)

var myView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,160,44))

myView.addSubview(toButton)
myView.addSubview(fromButton)

self.navigationItem.titleView = myView
```

fromButtonView and toButtonView are variables with the views implemented as xibs.

The resulting navigation header looks as follows, can't figure out where I am going awry.  The views are stacking on top of each other.

[image]

Comment: Possible dubplicated to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502101/button-in-the-middle-of-navigationbar

Comment: Different because they are doing it using images, and I have a xib for a subview of the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
let testFrame : CGRect = CGRectMake(0,0,180,40)

var buttonView: UIView = UIView(frame: testFrame)


var button1 =  UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton

button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40) as CGRect

button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

button.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)


var button2 =  UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton

button.frame = CGRectMake(70, 0, 40, 40) as CGRect

button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

button.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

buttonView.addSubview(button1)

buttonView.addSubview(button2)

self.navigationItem.titleView = buttonView
```

Comment: The button has a title and an image associated with it, that's why I am loading it as a custom view.